# Install docker on a compute cluster with a shared file-system

Tags: docker, cluster-computing, shared-directory

I have a compute cluster of 16 nodes running centos 6.7, with each node having a local disk and a shared storage between all nodes which is FhGFS based. the shared path is '/cluster'.

How to install Docker so that the image repository is allocated on /cluster, and any node could run containers from that repo. Is there a way to allocate the image repo in the shared area, while installing only the docker engine on each of the nodes? or even better, installing both the image repo and the engine on the shared area and making this installation usable by all nodes?

Answer (score 1):

You can just modify your docker daemon configs to have the runtime root be `/cluster`

```
docker daemon --graph="/cluster"
```

or

```
docker daemon -g "/cluster"
```

Say you are using `CentOS` or `RHEL` you could add these options under

```
/etc/sysconfig/docker
```

If you are using `Debian` or `Ubuntu` you would change:

```
/etc/defaults/docker
```

So this way all the pulls that you do for images will be stored under `/cluster` also all your container runtimes will be under `/cluster`. So if you mount `/cluster` on all your machines then all of them will be able to see them.

If you want to share the binary, just put it under say `/cluster/bin` and then add it to your `$PATH`.

You might also want to look at [Docker Swarm](https://docs.docker.com/swarm/) which is Docker's native clustering support. Although not ready for primetime as of Today, it's worth looking at.

Comment: Thanks @Rico, but I'm using docker 1.7.1 where 'daemon' is not a docker command. Do you suggest an alternative?

Comment: Ok, it is 'docker -d'. it worked also using 'service docker start' when I added '-g /cluster' in '/etc/sysconfig/docker'

Now about sharing of binaries. Speaking about nodes which don't have docker installed, which files/directories should I mount/add to path in order for these nodes to be able to run docker as a service? Is the executable (/usr/bin/docker) enough, or should I mount also '/etc/init.d/docker' the lock file,...etc?